# Show resolved comments on Google Docs in context without re-opening them?

Tags: google-docs

I have a Google Docs document when there were a lot of comments. These comments have been resolved, however, I still need to see them in context.

You *could* re-open them, but I don't really want to do that, since it would incorrectly notify many people.

So how would you show resolved comments in context without re-opening them in Google Docs document?

Comment: Please read the tags **before** posting your question.

Comment: I've already voted to do so. It might be faster for you to flag your question "in need of moderator intervention" and ask a mod to move it (be specific about where you want it moved to).

Comment: @DavidPostill I did at the same time ;) , thanks for your patience.

Comment: Did you find any solution to view Resolved comments ? I wonder how google's design team missed this pretty useful feature.

Comment: To just view them (no context), just use root's answer, I did not yet found solution how to display them in context without reopening them.

Comment: To view them (with context) you can export them to a spreadsheet. Hope [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/168333/305434) helps

Answer (score 40):

Click on "Comments" at the top right corner (marked in the image below). The resolved ones are listed there.
Source: [Link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/rWykueJZ8Ko;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/authorid$3AAPn2wQdMnjT2Cy95tR9Oi7jjt9rmg-oNTS-0OeugAiJ5UHtITX4DBzR9zjqZCmcYnlohtWKxhdm8%7Csort:date%7Cspell:false)

To see the original context of a comment, click on that comment. This will only work if the original context still exists (wasn't deleted). If the original context was deleted, you can [make a copy of an earlier version](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190843#copy_earlier_version) of the document, and view the comments there.

[image]

Comment: That does not show them in the original context.

Comment: @jave.web it does show the original context if you click on the comment. If the original context was deleted, you can restore it. See edited answer above.

Comment: The purpose is to globally show all the comments next to their contexts INSIDE THE DOCUMENT (as seen before they are marked as resolved).

Comment: It's now called "Open Comment History" and is a speech bubble icon on top right

Answer (score 5):

To complete Root's answer:

⚠ be aware that the last resolved comment won't be on the top of the list of this panel:  comments seem to be sorted by date/hour of creation.

It would be nice to have an option to sort them by "last resolved/edited": *if you think so too, send this kind of feedback to google* (in the menu go to **Help** → **Report a problem**. You can just copy paste what I've written below).  (Of course, google won't care, but you'd have tried).

> in the comment history panel: add an option "last edited/resolved"
>
> It's currently really difficult (if not impossible) to undo a comment
>   we just resolved since the comment aren't sorted by last
>   edited/resolved but by date of creation. So you need to know when the
>   comment was created (which isn't really possible) and then find a way
>   to retrieve it by reading and scrolling hundred of items, in this list
>   that takes forever to load every few items.

Comment: Totally agree with you, at the moment that function is almost useless.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:  In Google Docs, use the menu item: File > Make a copy

[image: Copy dialog]

In the Copy dialog, untick the "share it with the same people" but tick "copy comments and suggestions" and "include resolved comments and suggestions".

Now you have a new, identical document where you can re-open comments without, it seems, notifying many people about it.  it's not the same document, but for review purposes, it might do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this, is to export them all (regardless of whether they have been closed or deleted) to a spreadsheet, including their context (the highlighted part) as well as a link to the comment itself. This method will also allow you to filter and more easily search comment data, which can be helpful.

To do this, install the [Comments Exporter Add-On](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/comments_exporter/139083406033), open the document with comments and create an export:

[image]

After the export, a new spreadsheet will be created in your Home folder containing all of the comment data, which will look like this:

[image]